# How to install `sprof` in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, tools, compiler

I have a clean Docker `ubuntu:14.04` container. `sprof` is not installed in the base image. How do you install it? I assumed it would be part of `binutils` along with `gprof`, but it's not there.

Does anyone know how to install `sprof`?

Comment: @steeldriver Make an answer `apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc-dev` and I'll give you the checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `libc-dev-bin` package.

Found with :

```
$ apt-file search sprof | grep '/usr/bin/sprof'
```

so :

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libc-dev-bin
```